# Accessing global method with namespace in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to call a method in another .js file that looks like this:

```js
if (typeof Shared === "undefined" || !Shared) {
    var Shared = {};
}

Shared.HelperClass = (function ()
{
    // ... private stuff here

    return {
        Init: function()
        {

        },

        TestMethod: function(name)
        {
            return name;
        }
    };

})();
```

Naturally to call init in Javascript, i'd call:

```js
Shared.HelperClass.Init();
```

Now I have a TypeScript file i'd like to call this in, but it throws a compiler error because it doesn't know what it is.

How do I tell TypeScript about these methods such that I can call this code from my .ts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I tell TypeScript about these methods such that I can call this code from my .ts file?

Create a file `globals.d.ts` and add the following

```
declare var Shared:any;
```

Done!

## More

More on migrating : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/migrating.html

Comment: I guess I was making it way too hard on myself.  Thanks! :)